# Make docker only use one specific NIC

Tags: docker, networking

### The Setup

I am running docker on Debian, on a single host. The host runs all kinds of different services for my home network, like monitoring software, home automation, log aggregation and so on.
I started out with only one physical network adapter attached to the system, and created a few containers. Later, I added a secondary NIC, the idea being to move all docker containers on `eth1` while using `eth0` for ssh access to the docker host only.

**Version Information**

- Debian 10 "Buster"
- Docker `20.10.0`
- Kernel `4.19.0-13-amd64`
- systemd `241-7~deb10u5 amd64`
- storage driver `overlay2`

### The Problem

Docker currently publishes all containers both on NICs, and I can't find a clean and simple way to limit exposing services on `eth1` only. This is regardless of whether I use host, bridge or self-defined networks.

### Things I've tried without success

- Docker's `daemon.json` - set "ip" option. This looks like the most obvious solution to me, but it doesn't seem to have an effect, after reboots and service restarts services are still available on both network interfaces. I even recreated a container from scratch after introducing the "ip" option, also had no effect. Currently, the config looks very simple:

```
{
   "ip" : "192.168.1.10",
   "graph": "/srv/docker"
}
```

[Docker command line reference explaining what "ip" should do](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

### Things I've looked into, but don't like as a solution

- Blocking access to `eth0` on the firewall level, except p22. This would work but feels like a hack to me.
- Setting the fixed IP address on each container. I tried, and it does work, but I want to have this set as a default on the server level, rather than specifying it manually for each container. If the docker host IP would change, I'd have to manually edit it again for each container.

### Ideas?

There must be a (probably simple) way to change the host network from `0.0.0.0` to `eth1`'s specific IP address, but for the life of me I haven't been able to find out how.

Comment: Pls specify Docker, OS and kernel version. Do you use systemd? What file driver are you using?

Comment: I would like to see also how are you publishing ports of the container and container network space?

Comment: I don't think you would find a better solution then the those you wrote you didn't like. Firewall rules is a good solution, mapping to a specific ip on host and setting a static ip on the host is also a good solution. Another way is to map the host network to the container and handling it in your server code

Comment: I think the problem is DEFINITELY related to versions of your components. Pls specify Docker, OS and kernel version + systemd and file driver information.

Comment: Try this one https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2020/be-careful-docker-might-be-exposing-ports-world

Comment: @OlesyaBolobova I have included version information in the original post, in the first section. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @JanGaraj I have two containers running directly on the host network, so there was nothing for me to configure at all. One container (portainer) runs on the default network bridge, just because it was the default when I set it up in the beginning. The remaining containers are part of a stack for which a separate bridge network was defined.In the stack, there is one container exposing one single port: 0.0.0.0:8000 8000/tcp, and in my opinion, it should pick up the IP I set in daemon.json rather than 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can at least partially answer my own question. When specifying the "ip" parameter in docker's `daemon.json`, only *newly created* containers will respect that setting and only bind to the configured IP address. However, it is not enough to recreate an existing container, it will still bind to both NICs. You really have to delete any misbehaving containers including their volumes and configs and start from scratch. I have yet to find a way to just change the binding without having to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see reason to use host network for the container (host network = `--net=host` parameter for container). Why you don't use default container networking and then just publish ports on the correct IP with the advance publish port syntax (`-p IP:host_port:container_port`), e.g.:

```
-p <eth1-ip-address>:<host-app-port>:<container-app-port>
```

Doc: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports

Of course you can use host network for the container = `--net=host` parameter for container, but then don't bind all interfaces from the app (`0.0.0.0:<app-port>`), just start app on the specific eth1 IP.

Comment: I have read that net=host increases performance and allows for low level network access which is otherwise not possible. I never ran the two containers with default networking, but it doesn't seem to matter - the non-host-networking containers show the same behaviour by listening on all interfaces. The syntax you mentioned works, and I had already tried it, but it has me specify the interface address for each container, which can be a pain when the host IP changes for any reason. I'd rather have it pick up the IP to publish on from the daemon.json where there is a setting for just that.

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs / networking section

If you want to be more restrictive and only allow container services to be contacted through a specific external interface on the host machine, you have two choices. When you invoke docker run you can use either -p IP:host_port:container_port or -p IP::port to specify the external interface for one particular binding. Or if you always want Docker port forwards to bind to one specific IP address, you can edit your system-wide Docker server settings and add the option --ip=IP_ADDRESS. Remember to restart your Docker server after editing this setting.

Found some additional OS level security measures so you dont have to rely on a config file alone.

commercial hypervisor setup guides mention using 'ip-netns' to segment and isolate nics. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html

as a last resort you could edit the loopback iptable rules and block cross nic communication that way

Comment: Exactly - the second option, specifying a system-wide docker server setting whrough --ip=ADDR, is what I want to achieve. This setting is provided by docker and probably there for a reason, the problem is just that it doesn't get applied in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this problem whilst running up a pihole instance per VLAN and wanting to run up a series of docker containers within the one LXC container on proxmox.

***EDIT: the information given below is INCORRECT! I did in fact need to create a macvlan and attach that to the NIC. Otherwise the traffic hits the NIC but never goes any further.***

---

At first I thought I might need to create individual docker networks per instance, then attach each network to an external NIC. Luckily, this was not the case.

My solution was to attach a NIC to the LXC container for each VLAN and assign each interface a static ip address (10.0.x.53).

Then, use the `<host ip>:<host port>:<docker port>` syntax inside a docker-compose file for each instance of pihole. Each pihole container was named pihole-N, where N is the tag value of that VLAN. This simply forwards the traffic from the desired NIC, straight into each docker container on the desired port.

Here is an example of just one of these instances:

```
version: "3"

# More info at https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/ and https://docs.pi-hole.net/
services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole-10
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    ports:
      - "10.0.10.53:53:53/tcp"
      - "10.0.10.53:53:53/udp"
      - "10.0.10.53:67:67/udp"
      - "10.0.10.53:80:80/tcp"
    environment:
      TZ: 'UTC'
      WEBPASSWORD: <password>
    # Volumes store your data between container upgrades
    volumes:
      - '/opt/pihole-10/etc-pihole/:/etc/pihole/'
      - '/opt/pihole-10/etc-dnsmasq.d/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/'
    # Recommended but not required (DHCP needs NET_ADMIN)
    #   https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole#note-on-capabilities
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
```